# How to insert background image in cardview?

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on a react native application which has cards and which needs background images for cards.

How do I add Background images to cards?
I tried with `<ImageBackground>`, but the image is not getting fit to the cardview instead it gets stretched.

Below is the code that I am using,

```
<View style={[styles.container, { marginTop:0, alignItems: 'center' }]}>
   <CardView
    cornerRadius={10}
    style={styles.cardViewStyleFirst}>
     <ImageBackground 
      source = {require('../assets/weatherbg.png')}
      style = {styles.imageStyle} >
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize:22, textAlign:'left', color: '#000' }}>Weather Details</Text>
        <View style={{ flex:7 }}>
         <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize:20, textAlign:'center', color: '#000' }}>{this.state.data.name}</Text>
         <View style={{ alignItems:'center' }}>
         <Image source={{uri:`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${this.state.data.weather[0].icon}.png`}} style={{ height:80, width:80 }} />
         </View>

         <View>
          <Text style={{ color: '#000'  }}>Forecast : {this.state.data.weather[0].main}</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: '#000'  }}>Current Temperature : {this.state.data.main.temp} °C</Text>
         </View>
         </View>
     </ImageBackground>
    </CardView>  
</View>
```

Styles :

```
container: {
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: '#F0F0F0'
    },

cardViewStyleFirst:{
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      width: 340, 
      height: 250,
      alignItems: 'center'
    },

imageStyle:{ 
    width: 340, 
    height: '100%',

    }
```

Comment: Can you also add the necessary styles for the `CardView` and the `View`?

Comment: Added @PritishVaidya

Comment: Have you tired "resizeMode" on image styles?

Comment: @HungrySoul I tried, for 'cover' - It doesn't change', 'contain' - will get the image fit but top and bottom are cut, 'stretch' - will stretch the image

Answer (score 0):

imageStyle:{

```
width: 340, 
height: '100%',

}
```

100% doesn't work.
You have to make a constant at the top and use it in place of '100%'

Comment: I even tried giving the Card height which is of 250. It isn't working!

Comment: or you can use flex for height.  for reference :https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html

Answer (score -1):

```
render: function() {

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
      <View
        style={styles.card}
      >
        <Image source={{uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/91AR0Lo.jpg'}} style={styles.cardImage} />
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.textLeft}>Animal, 10</Text>
          <Text style={styles.textRight}>1 Connection</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
  </View>
);
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  card: {
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderRadius: 3,
    borderColor: '#000',
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    padding: 10
  },
  cardImage: {
    height: 260,
  },
  textLeft: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left:0,
    top:0
  },
  textRight: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    top: 0
  }
});
```

Comment: The question is related to React native. You have provided a solution for native android which cannot be used in this case.

Comment: ohh sorry.My mistake@Abhishek DS